# Applications Icons Missing after 20.04 update

Tags: desktop-icons

I just applied the recommended updates to my Ubuntu 20.04 (amd64) system.  After the reboot I am missing all my application icons that were on my desktop (usually on the left side of the primary display).  Is there a setting that I need to change?

Comment: Are the applications still present in the folder "Desktop" in your home folder? Can you still add/remove items to the desktop? Add such info to your question (use "edit"): it can help to identify the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.04 has the desktop function removed from Nautilus. There is a gnome-shell extension to restore desktop icons

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/